# passing user inputs to methods are not being added up correctly

Tags: java, user-input

I'm trying to write a program that asks the user for numbers until the user enters -1. The program will then provide the sum of the numbers. The program should use a Statistics object to calculate the sum.

There are, however, specifications that come with this project. Those are

> Do not modify the Statistics class in this part. Instead, implement the program for calculating the sum by making use of it.

```
public class Statistics {

    private int count;
    private int sum;
    //private double average;

    public Statistics() {
        this.count = 0;
    }

    public void addNumber(int number) {
        //sum += number;
        count++;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return this.count;
    }

    public int sum(int user) {
        this.sum = this.sum + user;
        return this.sum;
    }

    public double average() {
        double average;
        average = (double) sum / this.count;
        return average;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Statistics statistics = new Statistics();
        System.out.println("Enter Numbers:");
        int user=0;
        while (user >= 0) {
            statistics.sum(user = scan.nextInt());
        }
        System.out.println("Sum: " + statistics.sum(user));
    }
}
```

If I (the user) input `4,2,5,2,-1...` the program outputs `Sum: 11`. Why does it not equal `Sum: 15`?

Comment: Okay, so first when you don't provide full user input, but instead type '...', what do you expect? That we're wizards and can guess what was typed? Second, look at the sum method. You commented out the summing algorithm, and instead bump a counter for each entered number. What do you expect this function to return?

Comment: Why would it return 15? It should return 12. But it's not returning twelve because you invoke the `sum` method one more time *while* printing, thus adding `-1` to the sum

Comment: You did modify the Statistics class, did you?

Comment: It's about the sum method. Compare it to the average method, and the comment in addNumber.

Comment: First, let's make sure we're understanding this issue. there is "..." because that's the end of the user input. The while() loop states that "-1" ends the loop.  Therefore, we should know that the "-1" that I provided was the end had exhausted the user input. Moving on, I never call the addNumber() method. That's for a separate project,  so I apologize for being confusing with that component. The issue is in the sum() method because that's where the "user" input is being sent to. Thanks.

Comment: @TibetanMassive - If one of the answers resolved your issue, you can help the community by marking it as accepted. An accepted answer helps future visitors use the solution confidently.

Answer (score 2):

Pay attention to this snippet:

```
 int user=0;
    while (user >= 0) {
        statistics.sum(user = scan.nextInt());
    }
    System.out.println("Sum: " + statistics.sum(user));
```

1. you enter 4 -> `.sum` adds  4 to 0.  `sum=4;  user = 4 (user>=0 true)`
2. you enter 2 -> `.sum` adds  2 to 4.  `sum=6;  user = 2 (user>=0 true);`
3. you enter 5 -> `.sum` adds  5 to 6.  `sum=11; user = 5 (user>=0 true);`
4. you enter 2 -> `.sum` adds  2 to 11. `sum=13; user = 2 (user>=0 true);`
5. you enter-1 -> `.sum` adds -1 to 13. `sum=12; user =-1 (user>=0 false);`

and your *user* variable is `-1` at this time.

Finally you call `statistics.sum(user)` and that adds -1 to 12, which is `11`.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Accepting answers which helped you in finding solution is always a good gesture.

Answer (score 2):

This question is from [mooc.fi's Java Programming Part 4](https://java-programming.mooc.fi/part-4/1-introduction-to-object-oriented-programming) Programming exercise "Statistics".

In part 2 you should implement the class `Statistics`.
Below it contains a part that shows how this class is used:

> ```
> public class Main {
>     public static void main(String[] args) {
>         Statistics statistics = new Statistics();
>         statistics.addNumber(3);
>         statistics.addNumber(5);
>         statistics.addNumber(1);
>         statistics.addNumber(2);
>         System.out.println("Count: " + statistics.getCount());
>         System.out.println("Sum: " + statistics.sum());
>         System.out.println("Average: " + statistics.average());
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> The program prints the following:
>
> ```
> Count: 4
> Sum: 11
> Average: 2.75
> ```

Before moving to part 3, make sure your `Statistics` class produces the right output when used with that Main.

Once you got this working, move to the next part.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it is from the MOOC. So when I did that part of the project, I was able to get the correct output, but I couldn't ever get the submission point for it. It kept saying how the average should start at <0.0>. It wouldn't accept my code because apparently my average started at <NaN>. I don't know what "starts at" means either so I just moved on.

Comment: Yeah, just return 0 if the count is 0.

Answer (score 1):

> If I (the user) input 4,2,5,2,-1... the program outputs Sum: 11. Why
>   does it not equal Sum: 15?

It is happening because you are calling `statistics.sum` at two places (one, inside the `while` loop and one, after the `while` loop). The following code will help you trace how it is working:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Statistics {

    private int count;
    private int sum;
    // private double average;

    public Statistics() {
        this.count = 0;
    }

    public void addNumber(int number) {
        // sum += number;
        count++;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return this.count;
    }

    public int sum(int user) {
        System.out.println("Got " + user);// Add this line for tracing 
        this.sum = this.sum + user;
        return this.sum;
    }

    public double average() {
        double average;
        average = (double) sum / this.count;
        return average;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Statistics statistics = new Statistics();
        System.out.println("Enter Numbers:");
        int user = 0;
        while (user >= 0) {
            statistics.sum(user = scan.nextInt());
        }
        System.out.println("Sum: " + statistics.sum(user));
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter Numbers:
4
Got 4
2
Got 2
5
Got 5
2
Got 2
-1
Got -1
Got -1
Sum: 11
```

Ths, the final result has been calculated as `4 + 2 + 5 + 2 + (-1) + (-1) = 11`

Comment: This helped me understand why I was getting 11. Thank you.